# Why got all content using Jquery load by selector

Tags: jquery

All, I have a little problem with the jquery `load` method usage. please help to review it .
Say you have the source html(url is templetes/templetesList.html) like below.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <ol id="layoutol">
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img alt=""
            src="templetes/thumbnails/e6a9bb54da25102b9a032db401e887ec.PNG" /></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img alt=""
            src="templetes/thumbnails/a709bb54da25102b9a032db401e8aded.PNG" /></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img alt=""
            src="templetes/thumbnails/cad4bb54da25102b9a032db401e855a.PNG" /></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img alt=""
            src="templetes/thumbnails/12344bb54da25102b9a032db401edddd.PNG" /></li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

The script looks like below.

```
$("#layoutol").load("templetes/templetesList.html li",function(data){alert(data);});
```

as the doc says the data will be the responsetext.

But why I got all the html content instead of the `li` content ? 
I mean I only need the `li` part.

```
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img alt=""
            src="templetes/thumbnails/e6a9bb54da25102b9a032db401e887ec.PNG" /></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img alt=""
            src="templetes/thumbnails/a709bb54da25102b9a032db401e8aded.PNG" /></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img alt=""
            src="templetes/thumbnails/cad4bb54da25102b9a032db401e855a.PNG" /></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><img alt=""
            src="templetes/thumbnails/12344bb54da25102b9a032db401edddd.PNG" /></li>
```

Did I miss something ? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting a selector to `.load` in that manner will indeed load only the selected content into your target, but the response text will still be that of the complete request. What happens is that a request for the entire document is submitted, and the content matching your selector is filtered out post hoc. This does not affect the content of the response text.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mMeLS/)

Note how only the `li` elements are loaded into the list, but the entire source is logged in `console.log`

Comment: Hi, @David, If I only need the selector content by ajax, for the sake of the performance . How to make it ?thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang: since you'll be loading the stripped content into a target element, you could check the content of that element, rather than looking at the response text. `$('#layoutol').html()` should give you only the selected content. Note that in all cases you'll be downloading the entire document from the remote server, and the filtering is performed on the client after the request is completed.

Comment: If you want to minimize bandwidth by filtering at your server side, you're going to have to implement some checks at your server, to see whether the current request is such an AJAX request, and return only the required content. This will probably best be achieved with flags and a preconfiguration of what you'll be requesting ("if we receive an ajax request, only render this part"). You'll have a hard time implementing the sizzle selectors on your server.

Comment: Yeah , `minimize bandwidth` is what i mean , I think you mean implement something like `servlet` in java or `httphandler` in .net. right ?thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang: Yeah, if you want to minimize bandwidth, you need to route the request through some server side code, and the exact solution would depend on your server. Like you say, it could be achieved with a `HttpHandler` in .NET. Looking for the header `X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest` is usually a good way to detect an AJAX request, and based on that you could decide to only yield the `li` elements. Note that the selector won't be passed to the server, but that is of less importance, as I really don't recommend rolling your own selector parser server-side.

Comment: Ok, I see, This solution is little complicated. the bad of this is selector is no use any more. We must implement the selector in the server side .thanks.

Comment: Oh, it will be complicated. And it's a very different question from the current one. Consider creating a new question if you want assistance on how to make your server return only a specific part of an AJAX call. Be sure to let people know what server-side language you're using.